# how to merged list of lists of nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

*I have a dictionary like this:*

```
{'CO,': {u'123456': [55111491410]},
 u'OA,': {u'3215': [55111400572]},
 u'KO,': {u'asdas': [55111186735],u'5541017924': [55111438755]},
 u'KU': {u'45645': [55111281815],u'546465238': [55111461870]},
 u'TU': {u'asdfds': [55111161462],u'546454149': [55111128782],
  u'546454793': [55111167133],u'546456387': [55111167139],
  u'546456925': [55111167140],u'546458931': [55111226912],
  u'546458951': [55111226914],u'546459861': [55111226916],
  u'546460165': [55111403171, 55111461858]}}
```

**I want to get merged list of all the lists in nested dictionary.**

Output should be like this:

```
[55111491410,55111400572,55111186735,55111438755,55111281815,55111461870,55111167133,55111167139,....55111403171,55111461858]
```

Comment: Does the order matter since dictionaries are unordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant answer based on regex and on the fact that all the values of interest are among square brackets

```
import re

pat = r'(?<=\[).+?(?=\])'

s = """{'CO,': {u'123456': [55111491410]},
 u'OA,': {u'3215': [55111400572]},
 u'KO,': {u'asdas': [55111186735],u'5541017924': [55111438755]},
 u'KU': {u'45645': [55111281815],u'546465238': [55111461870]},
 u'TU': {u'asdfds': [55111161462],u'546454149': [55111128782],
  u'546454793': [55111167133],u'546456387': [55111167139],
  u'546456925': [55111167140],u'546458931': [55111226912],
  u'546458951': [55111226914],u'546459861': [55111226916],
  u'546460165': [55111403171, 55111461858]}}"""

print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, re.findall(pat, s))))
```

Output

```
[55111491410, 55111400572, 55111186735, 55111438755, 55111281815, 55111461870, 55111161462, 55111128782, 55111167133, 55111167139, 55111167140, 55111226912, 55111226914, 55111226916, 55111403171, 55111461858]
```

Answer (score 1):

xJust a list comprehension using the dict's values and the inner dict values would do the job. But do remember that dicts are not ordered in python till 3.6. So if you are using the older version, the resulting list would also not be in any order

```
>>> dct = {'CO,': {u'123456': [55111491410]},
...  u'OA,': {u'3215': [55111400572]},
...  u'KO,': {u'asdas': [55111186735],u'5541017924': [55111438755]},
...  u'KU': {u'45645': [55111281815],u'546465238': [55111461870]},
...  u'TU': {u'asdfds': [55111161462],u'546454149': [55111128782],
...   u'546454793': [55111167133],u'546456387': [55111167139],
...   u'546456925': [55111167140],u'546458931': [55111226912],
...   u'546458951': [55111226914],u'546459861': [55111226916],
...   u'546460165': [55111403171, 55111461858]}}
>>> 
>>> [e for idct in dct.values() for lst in idct.values() for e in lst]
[55111491410, 55111400572, 55111186735, 55111438755, 55111281815, 55111461870, 55111161462, 55111128782, 55111167133, 55111167139, 55111167140, 55111226912, 55111226914, 55111226916, 55111403171, 55111461858]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'CO,': {u'123456': [55111491410]},
     u'OA,': {u'3215': [55111400572]},
     u'KO,': {u'asdas': [55111186735], u'5541017924': [55111438755]},
     u'KU': {u'45645': [55111281815], u'546465238': [55111461870]},
     u'TU': {u'asdfds': [55111161462], u'546454149': [55111128782],
             u'546454793': [55111167133], u'546456387': [55111167139],
             u'546456925': [55111167140], u'546458931': [55111226912],
             u'546458951': [55111226914], u'546459861': [55111226916],
             u'546460165': [55111403171, 55111461858]}}
z = []
for i in d.keys():
    for j in d[i].keys():
        z.append(d[i][j][0])

print(z)
```

**output:**

```
[55111491410, 55111400572, 55111186735, 55111438755, 55111281815, 55111461870, 55111161462, 55111128782, 55111167133, 55111167139, 55111167140, 55111226912, 55111226914, 55111226916, 55111403171]
```